# Setting up an Artifactory instance to mirror another Artifactory

Tags: artifactory, mirror

We would like to have two JFrog Artifactory instances, one for users inside local network of the company (with complete open access) and one that can be used from outside (with restricted accesses). So we want the second instance mirror some (or all) of repositories of the first one. Where should I start?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would probably want to have [Remote Repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Smart+Remote+Repositories) that point to the inner network instance (it has to be reachable from outside your network, but only for the credentials you specify on the remote repository's configuration though) so that they can serve whatever is in the inner instance's repositories when requested.

Another option is to use [Replication](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Replication) (which runs periodically) to sync (mirror) a repository from the outside instance with the inner one.

I would probably go with the first option as you will not have to wait for replication cycles to complete to be sure the outer instance is completely synced, replication is more of a DR usecase.

Comment: I tried with remote repositories. I could not figure out how to mirror only one repo e.g. libs-snapshot?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... if you set up a remote repository with libs-snapshot's url (i.e. `art.company.com:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot`) it will effectively 'mirror' that repo, meaning it will serve whatever is in libs-snapshot -- have you read the documentation I referenced?

Comment: I found the problem. We are using opensource version of Artifactory. Smart remote repositories is a feature for paid version.